# Cannot import module

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have created a python web app with this directory structure:

```
# cd /usr/local/www/myapp

modules
    layout
        __init__.py
        layout.py
packages
public
myapp.wsgi
```

I have set my PYTHONPATH to:

```
/usr/local/www/myapp/modules:/usr/local/www/myapp/packages
```

In myapp.wsgi I try to do:

```
import layout
```

But I am getting Internal server error. Why?

This is my myapp.wsgi (if I remove the import layout line, it works):

```
import sys
import wsgiref
import layout    
def application(environ, start_response):
        response_status = '200 OK'
        response_body = 'Hello! '
        response_headers = []
        content_type = ('Content-type', 'text-plain')
        content_length = ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))
        response_headers.append(content_type)
        response_headers.append(content_length)
        start_response(response_status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]
```

Full error message I am getting:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/myapp/public

    <Directory /usr/local/www/myapp/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/myapp>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Error from /var/log/httpd-error.log:

```
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123] mod_wsgi (pid=1725): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123] mod_wsgi (pid=1725): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123]   File "/usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123]     import layout
[Fri Jan 20 15:31:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.201.123] ImportError: No module named layout
```

Output of print sys.path:

[image]

Comment: At least include the full and exact error message you are getting.

Comment: How are you running the web server? It's most likely not using your environment, so setting PYTHONPATH for your own shell won't help.

Comment: I am using Apache mod_wsgi and I have created a virtual host for /usr/local/www/myapp.

Comment: @unwind Added error message I am getting in the browser and my virtual host configuration.

Comment: The error message you've posted is not the error message we're looking for---as it notes, check the server error log.  Look for a python "Traceback".  Also, I wonder if you're just specifying the import incorrectly.  If `layout.py` contains the code of interest, you need to do `import layout.layout` or `from layout import layout`.

Comment: @jrennie I have added error from var/log/httpd-error.log. I also tried import layout.layout but it throws the same error.

Comment: I'd bet on @Wooble's theory---the server is using a different PYTHONPATH.  Try printing/logging `sys.path` from your script to see (you'll need to `import sys` first).

Comment: @jrennie I added output of print sys.path to my question.

Comment: @RichardKnop: The useful thing is to get your script to print/log sys.path when that script is executed by the web server.  If the `modules` dir is not part of `sys.path`, then `import layout` will fail.  Note that the `modules` dir is not in your `sys.path` example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First try:

```
python /usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi
```

Does it load correctly?

If yes, then probably you have some environment (in `~/.bashrc` or such) which is needed for your app. Try::

```
# to wipe-out extra env
env -i bash
# try again
python /usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi
```

Verify you use same python in your shell as the one used by apache WSGI.

If your `myapp.wsgi` need any extra env to load correctly, then you can do one of:

- set [python path](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) in apache, or
- set in runtime in your myapp.wsgi

To set in in your WSGI code, here is the example code.

```
import os, sys
EXTRA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
if EXTRA_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(EXTRA_DIR)
```

Put in in the beginning of your myapp.wsgi file.

Comment: I tried all of that. Nothing worked. env -i bash doesn't work because I am using FreeBSD.

Comment: if you cannot do `env -i` then inspect manually your environment `env` command and your profile scripts. Do you use a virtualenv or such?

Comment: what is the output of `python /usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi` ?

Comment: Look in my question. I included the excerpt from httpd-error.log. The same error appears in shell when I write python /usr/local/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi. It works when I add this line on top of the file: sys.path.append('/usr/local/www/myapp/modules').

Comment: @RichardKnop: as in my post, you need to use WSGIPythonPath in apache config or do sys.path.append() in your wsgi code.

Comment: @RichardKnop: more specifically, add `WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/www/myapp/modules` to your apache config

Comment: WSGIPythonPath only applies if using mod_wsgi embedded mode. For daemon mode you use python-path option to WSGIDaemonProcess directive. It is recommended to use daemon mode if you have no idea about how to set up Apache properly as it is more forgiving of fact that defaults in Apache aren't very good for fat Python web applications.

Comment: This worked for me.  Getting wsgi.py to execute fine on the command line with `python directory/wsgi.py` fixed my issue.  Seems like a no brainer.

Answer (score 1):

You have `__init.__py` in your `layout` folder, but it should be `__init__.py`. The period is misplaced. I am not sure if this is a typo in your post or not, but if that's what your file looks like it would cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

modules directory also needs a `__init__.py` file to be defined as a package.

Comment: `modules` isn't a package (based on the indicated `PYTHONPATH`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this solved it:

```
chmod a+x myapp.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  http://webpy.org/install#apachemodwsgi

> If you get an "ImportError: No module named web" in your apache error.log file, you could try setting the absolute path in code.py before importing web:

```
import sys, os
abspath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(abspath)
os.chdir(abspath)
import web
```

It works for me dramatically.